# @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) is not working with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I have a code in class:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ApiModels {

    private String address;
    private String age;
    private String name; 
}
```

When i'm trying to set only **address**:

```
public class TestClass {
    ApiModels models = new ApiModels();
    @Test
    void someMethod() {

        models.setAddress("Some address");

        System.out.println(models);
    }
}
```

I see all this output:

`ApiModels(address=Some address, age=null, name=null)`

But i don't need null values. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing object as String not the serialized Json. If you serialize object to Json then it will not show null fields. To see the use of `@Jsoninclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` check the following code.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

ApiModels apm = new ApiModels('no: 23','12',NULL);
String serializedAPM = mapper.writeValueAsString(apm);
System.out.println(serializedAPM);
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(models)` will invoke the `.toString()` and show you the results. None of this is JSON related - `@JsonInclude` and co are relevant when you ask *the json serializer* to serialize your object. At which point, the `null` values will not be sent.

Lombok is generating your toString method in your snippet. It cannot be told to 'skip' `null` values and you probably don't want to: `toString()` output is solely for debugging, any structured string data (such as a JSON dump of your object) should be done via other methods.